# Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\JR's Computer\Desktop\COMT\Actual Cellar App\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this error:

> "Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\JR's
>   Computer\Desktop\COMT\Actual Cellar App\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"

This code here shows my `build.gradle`, I have completedly no idea where I went wrong so it would be nice if anyone can tell me what are the possible fixes for this situation?

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task customClean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "sg.edu.tp.cellarapp"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

        compile 'com.github.iammert:InteractivePlayerView:f4f6490290'
    }
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sg.edu.tp.cellarapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".tophits" />
        <activity android:name=".topmusichitspage" />
        <activity android:name=".PlaySongActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".homescreen" />
        <activity android:name=".login" />
        <activity android:name=".signup" />
        <activity android:name=".explorescreen" />
        <activity android:name=".searchmylib" />
        <activity android:name=".welcome" />
        <activity android:name=".bartist" />
        <activity android:name=".b2artist" />
        <activity android:name=".b2album" />
        <activity android:name=".searchscreen" />
        <activity android:name=".Search" />
        <activity android:name=".Myplaylist" />
        <activity android:name=".playmuisc"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created your project in a folder structure which contains space. Your structure contains - `Actual Cellar App` in the path.

Create your project in a folder which doesn't has space and should work